# How to get UserID in OWIN OAuth .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth

I am following this article to achieve OAuth authentication:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

You can find ExternalLoginCallback controller's action.
In that action following method is executed:

```
ExternalLoginInfo loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

loginInfo has Login property. Login property has LoginProvider and ProviderKey properties.

Does anyone know what is it ProviderKey property? Is it unique UserID who is registered into provider?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `User.Identity.GetUserId()` method.

```
if (loginInfo == null)
{
    return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
}

var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

for more infromation see [Get more information from Social providers used in the VS 2013 project templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates.aspx) post.

Update: another way to get user is:

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
if (loginInfo == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}

var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
if (user != null)
{
    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. So, you think that mentioned method return unique userId from provider (e.g. Facebook)? What is about Login property?

Comment: According to it's documentation `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync` extracts login info out of an external identity. it is a generic method and it provides just the data needed to identify the user. The returned value contains default user name, name of the third party provider and an authentication ID. It doesn’t provide vendor specific details about a user